# TurboVPN for ubuntu server and set the only avaibile desktop to be xfce4 for all users

Tags: login, xfce, lightdm, desktop-environments, vnc

I am setting up a new Ubuntu server for several users 
My target is everyone could connect it with the TurboVPN by the server IP when user login to it, it will show the login screen to users and enter or choose the user name and then they can get their own desktop environment

Here are my questions:

1. The `lightdm.conf` seems can use`VNCserver` to generate the login
   screen for users so that users can login by the ip address without
   adding `:1` `:2` etc, but I only could achieve with the default vnc
   (tightvnc?). How could I change to TurboVPN? because it is called by
   `/opt/Turbo/bin/vncserver` the `VNCserver` in `lightdm` seems could not call turboVPN directly by that command.
2. I have tried to manually create the vnc server and when I log in to it, it is the Gnome desktop. How could I change all the users default desktop to be xfce4 at once and limit all users from VNC only could use it?

Thank you for helping...

Comment: Sorry for missing the version number: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
and I've mess up that's not lubuntu, that is gnome
I am quite new in Linux and trying recognize every things with it
Thanks for the help

Comment: thanks for the advice. Actually I have a simply wish : after i created a new user account , user login it by VNC will auto choose the xfce4 to be the desktop environment.